# Docker GLIBC Version Wrong - React Project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, docker, glibc

I am at a bit of a loss after doing some searching. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I am moving a react project to a docker container for a client, as they want to deploy with containers, and am getting this error after the project runs `npm start` to launch the dev server. The dev server does officially launch, but it won't compile the react app.

`` Error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /app/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-88/binding.node) ``

I have done some reading around and found that this is the module for the gnu linux c library (hopefully I am wording that correctly). From what I can tell with the error, my react application is looking for version 2.29 of GLIBC but the docker container only has version 2.24.

To test this I ran lld by attaching a bash shell to the docker container.

`sudo docker exec -it my-docker-container-id bash`

`ldd --version`

returns

`ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.24-11+deb9u4) 2.24 Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.`

I have had no problems running the react dev server on my own environment.. so I ran the same command on my host computer and got version 2.32.

Host computer returns...

`ldd (GNU libc) 2.32 Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.`

So this makes sense... I need version 2.29, I have version 2.32 locally on the host, but the container only has version 2.24. My next thought was to look at the Dockerfile to see how it's loading everything.

Here is the Dockerfile for the react project:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN chown -Rh $user:$user /app
USER $user
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My next thought is to try to use `FROM ubuntu:latest` instead of `node:latest` and manually install npm during the docker build (EDIT* actually I don't know if this is even possible). This is probably not the best way of doing this, so I am here looking for some help. Thanks!

Comment: The `RUN npm install` step will install packages in the image's `node_modules` directory; do you list `node_modules` in a `.dockerignore` file, so the host's (potentially different) `node_modules` tree doesn't get copied into the image?

Comment: I am an idiot and forgot to list node_modules here. I am going to pop this in and rebuild now.

Comment: Hmm. I rebuilt with the node_modules listed here in the .dockerignore file. Still having the same error

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference -- I deleted the old container and image and rebuilt from scratch and still get the same error.

Comment: Got it! I deleted my local node_modules folder and everything worked. If you make an answer I can select yours. 

Thanks for taking time to point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Change `FROM node:latest` to `FROM node:14`

I use node-sass v4.14.1 and in my case it helped. According to the [release](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.14.1) highest supported node version is 14.